# Finding perimeter given two angles and a side

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the perimeter of the land to the nearest tenth in the following diagram. 455

So I know all angles must add up to $180$ so the missing angle is $55$, but how do I use this information along with any other laws like the cosine law and the sine law? I know the perimeter is just adding up all the sides, but I am missing two of them.

[image]

Comment: The law sines will help you to find the side lengths

Comment: $$\frac{sinA}{a}=\frac{sinB}{b}=\frac{sinC}{c}$$

Comment: is there a particular side I should find first? like the longest side?

Comment: You have been given $a, A$ and $B.$  $C = 180 - A - B.$  And the law of sines will let you use $a,$ and the sines of the angles to find $b, c$

Comment: @Doug M, does the solution below look correct to you? it makes sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given $a = 14, A = 73^\circ, B= 52^\circ$

$C = 180 - 73 - 52 = 55^\circ$

Law of sines

$\frac {a}{\sin A} = \frac {b}{\sin B} = \frac {c}{\sin C}$

Fill in the values that we already know.

$\frac {14}{\sin 73^\circ} = \frac {b}{\sin 52^\circ } = \frac {c}{\sin 55^\circ}$

We can break this up into pieces.

i.e. $\frac {14}{\sin 73^\circ} = \frac {b}{\sin 52^\circ }$ and  $\frac {14}{\sin 73^\circ}= \frac {c}{\sin 55^\circ}$

Each can be solved via cross multiplication.

When you have $b,c$ it becomes elementary to find $a+b+c$

Comment: thanks for the answer, this was very clear and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

By law of sines: $\frac{14}{sin73^{ \circ }} = \frac{x}{sin52^{ \circ }} = \frac{y}{sin55^{ \circ }} \implies$

$x = \frac{14 sin52^{ \circ }}{sin73^{ \circ }}$

$y = \frac{14 sin55^{ \circ }}{sin73^{ \circ }}$

Therefore your perimeter is $ = 14+x+y= 14 + \frac{14(sin52^{ \circ }+sin55^{ \circ })}{sin73^{ \circ }} = 14 \cdot \frac{sin73^{ \circ } + sin52^{ \circ }+sin55^{ \circ }}{sin73^{ \circ }}$

Comment: how did you solve the total perimeter like that?